# Is there an abstract way to get all properties of an entity in java?

Tags: java, properties, entity

I am using Netbeans 7.2.1 on windows 7.

I am trying to get all the properties of an entity and store them in a String array. I want to do this in the most general way I can think of, so a method like the one in jCSV:

```
public void writeAll(List<E> data) throws IOException {
    for (E e : data) {
        write(e);
    }
}
```

You can find that package here: https://code.google.com/p/jcsv/

```
public String[] getProperties( E e ){

    String [] properties = new String[ e.numberOfProperties ];
    int i = -1;

    for ( P p : e ) {

        i += 1;
        properties[i] = p.toString(); // OR properties[i] = e.getProperty[i].toString();

    }

    return properties;
}
```

I feel like there should be some way of doing this with [the Properties class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) but I can't figure out a way to use it to get properties *from* an entity. I think it's just something simple, but I can't see where.

Comment: Do you want a generic way of reading all the properties of an POJO ?

Comment: Take a look at `java.beans.Introspector`.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Why can't you just ask the object to tell you what it is?  Sounds like poor encapsulation to me.

Comment: Thank you Ian Roberts, exactly what I needed. Also, I want to do this for more than one object, and I want to make it as automated as I can (if I could make it abstract, that would be ideal, but I think that's beyond me for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ian Roberts alluded to check out the java Introspector class [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html). The class is only useful if you are using standard Java beans naming conventions for accessing the properties of your entity.

What you'll want to do is get the `BeanInfo` of the class using the `Introspector#getBeanInfo(Class beanClass)` method then use the `getMethodDescriptors()` method of the `BeanInfo` to retrieve all of the "getter" methods of the bean. From there you can iterate over them and get the properties of your entity and call `toString()` on them.

One of the advantages of using this class as opposed to just using plain old reflection is that it caches the `BeanInfo` of the class after it has introspected on it allowing for a performance gain. You also do not have to hardcode anything like `get` or `set` in your reflective code.

Here's an example of what your `getProperties` method would look like using the introspector:

```
public <T> String[] getProperties(T entity){
    String[] properties = null;
    try {
        BeanInfo entityInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(entity.getClass());
        PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = entityInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();
        properties = new String[propertyDescriptors.length];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < propertyDescriptors.length ; i++){
            Object propertyValue = propertyDescriptors[i].getReadMethod().invoke(entity);
            if(propertyValue != null){
                properties[i] = propertyValue.toString();
            } else {
                properties[i] = null;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        //Handle your exception here.
    }
    return properties;
}
```

This example compiles and runs.

Keep in mind Apache Commons also has a library [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils//) which can be very helpful with things like this as well specifically (Javadoc [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils//api/)).

Comment: Thank you very much - I had gone off experimenting, but if I'd just checked back more often you would have saved me some effort! In any case, thank you for helping me out quite a bit, this is exactly what I needed to do. This will make my life a lot easier.